# React pass Array from Parent state to child state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a parent component holding a state called nodes which is established as an array. I am trying to pass this.state.nodes to a child component and have that component have the array as part of the child component state, but it's not working. Here is the code:

```
 <ChildComponent nodes={this.state.graphNodes}/>
```

This is in the return statement. After some testing/console logging I know the prop  is being passed.

In the child component, I have:

```
this.state = {
    nodes: this.props.nodes,
    links: [],
    totalNodes: [],
    totalLinks: []
}
```

But when I try to reference it or map it or do anything with it in the child component render or return it's telling me it's an empty array.

Comment: Do you call `super(props);` in the child component constructor? It might also be that `this.state.graphNodes` in your parent component is fetched asynchronously, so when you first render the child component it is not set yet.

Comment: show a more complete example of your ChildComponent code.  Also, just use `this.props.nodes` in your child render function

Comment: ...and anyway it's typically bad choice to put things from `proprs` to `state`. better iterate over `this.props.nodes` in child's `render()`

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. You were all correct ... this.props.nodes used directly instead of placing it in the child component state worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Since `graphNodes` is in a component state, i think its initial value should be an empty array, and you are initializing state with `props.nodes` at `constructor`, since `constructor` renders only once at initialization stage of the component at that moment `graphNodes` must be an empty array, after you change the parent component state, the state in the child component will not update. That makes `graphNodes` state always an empty array.

Why don't you use `props` directly, if you don't have to change the `graphNodes` values in the child component you can use it directly from `props`.

If you really want map `props` to `state`, you have to do it in `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method with proper conditions

Comment: I second the suggestion to use props.nodes directly. Because an array in js is an "object", you will pass the array as a reference instead of as a copy, meaning you will be using the same set of data on both the parent and child component. If the data updates, I would suggest having a function/method passed to the child component to change the state on the parent component, and the changes will also be reflected in the child component via props.nodes

Comment: Thanks Ozzy! You were correct and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

All of the comments were dead on. Using this.props.nodes directly instead of trying to put it in child state was the perfect solution. Thanks to all who replied!